# Automatic Form Completed With PHP Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two textboxes namely no_id and customer_name. when the user enters no_id, customer_name is filled in automatically.

**Form**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="no_id" onkeyup="autofill()" id="no_id">
  <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" readonly>
  <!--textbox customer_name is readonly-->
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autofill(){
  var no_id = $("#no_id").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data:"no_id="+no_id ,
  }).success(function (data) {
    var json = data,
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    $('#customer_name').val(obj.customer_name);
  });
}
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
include 'conn.php';
$npwp = $_GET['no_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ms where no_id='$no_id'");
$ms = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$data = array(
            'customer_name'      =>  $ms['customer_name']);
echo json_encode($data);
```

The scripts above works for me.

Now I want to modify it. 
When the `no_id` entered is **NOT** stored in the database, the `customer_name` box attribute becomes **readonly=false**, so the user can fill in `customer_name` box.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery onChange method on `no_id` input to send `no_id` value and search it's stored in the database or not and return true or false (0 or 1)like this code:

```
$('#no_id')onchange(function(){
var no_id = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data:"no_id="+no_id ,
  }).success(function (data) {
    if(data == true){
        $('#customer_name').attr('readonly');
    }else if(data == false){
        $('#customer_name').removeAttr('readonly');
    }
  });

});
```

I prefer to create another function for `no_id` onChange method

Answer (score -1):

Here I am counting `rows` in `mysql` and if rows == 0, then removing `readonly` attribute

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autofill(){
        var no_id = $("#no_id").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:"no_id="+no_id ,
            success : function (data) {
                var json = data;
                obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    if(obj.success=='true') {
                    $('#customer_name').val(obj.customer_name).attr("readonly", true);
                } else {
                    $('#customer_name').val("").attr("readonly", false);
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

**AJAX.php**

```
include 'conn.php';
$npwp = $_GET['no_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ms where no_id='$npwp'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1 ) {
    $ms = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $data = array('customer_name' =>  $ms['customer_name'], 'success'=>'true');
    echo json_encode($data); 
} else {
    $data = array('success'=>'false');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: @Dharman I think you have downvoted my answer. Apart from MySql injection sort of things, what are the other bugs in my answer ?